# How to get the entity after form.save()

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have form class which receive the `POST` request from web browswer.

```
class WaveFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WaveFile
        fields = ('description', 'document', )
```

then it will be saved as model entity by `form.save()`

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = WaveFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print(form.cleaned_data.get('document'))// it returns filename, but I want to have saved file path, so I want entity itself
        WaveFile.objects.get("(saved_one)")
```

But now I want to get the entity immediatelly it self which is saved by `form.save()`

How can I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.save()` will return the instance, so:

```
wave_file = form.save()
```